# How Would I Format An Array Like This?

Tags: arrays, node.js

Just wondering how I could come about formatting this array.

Here's an example of the array:

`[ itemone:"One", itemtwo:"Two" ]`

I want it to log something like this:

```
itemone - One
itemtwo - Two
```

Answer (score 2):

Use an object instead.

```js
const myObject = {itemone:"One", itemtwo:"Two"}
console.log(myObject);
```

Arrays are supposed to have numeric indicies only, not named properties (other than `.length`).

Comment: How Could I Push A Item To A Object?

Like A array.push(item)

Comment: Assign to a property of the object. `myObject.somePropName = item`